Unable to Connect to Redis: Test Failures in Quarkus Environment
I'm encountering an issue with my Quarkus application where I'm unable to establish a connection to Redis during testing, resulting in failures.

I have a Quarkus application that relies on Redis for data storage.

I have installed Redis on my Pc.

During testing, attempts to connect to Redis (192.168.1.100:6379) are failing.

I've confirmed that Redis is running on the specified IP address (192.168.1.100) and port (6379) using tools like telnet and ping, which are also unsuccessful.

The test failures seem related to Redis not being available or accessible during the test execution.

Checked Redis configuration (redis.conf) to ensure it's listening on the correct IP and port.

Verified firewall settings to ensure that traffic on port 6379 is allowed.

Attempted direct connection using redis-cli from the command line, which also failed.

Investigated possible network issues (e.g., ping and telnet not reaching the Redis server).


This the log console when I try to run tests:
C:\Users\U765123\.jdks\openjdk-20\bin\java.exe -ea -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" -Dquarkus.test.profile=test,jenkins -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=20696:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 @C:\Users\U765123\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_arg_file523591125 com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit5 @w@C:\Users\U765123\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_working_dirs_junit1.tmp @C:\Users\U765123\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_junit1.tmp
2024-04-08 11:53:51,056 INFO  [org.tes.doc.DockerClientProviderStrategy] (build-21) Loaded org.testcontainers.dockerclient.NpipeSocketClientProviderStrategy from ~/.testcontainers.properties, will try it first
2024-04-08 11:53:52,278 INFO  [org.tes.doc.DockerClientProviderStrategy] (build-21) Found Docker environment with local Npipe socket (npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine)
2024-04-08 11:53:52,303 INFO  [org.tes.DockerClientFactory] (build-21) Docker host IP address is localhost
2024-04-08 11:53:52,384 INFO  [org.tes.DockerClientFactory] (build-21) Connected to docker: 
  Server Version: 20.10.20
  API Version: 1.41
  Operating System: Docker Desktop
  Total Memory: 25385 MB
2024-04-08 11:53:52,558 INFO  [org.tes.ima.PullPolicy] (build-21) Image pull policy will be performed by: DefaultPullPolicy()
2024-04-08 11:53:52,568 INFO  [org.tes.uti.ImageNameSubstitutor] (build-21) Image name substitution will be performed by: DefaultImageNameSubstitutor (composite of 'ConfigurationFileImageNameSubstitutor' and 'PrefixingImageNameSubstitutor')
2024-04-08 11:53:52,595 INFO  [org.tes.DockerClientFactory] (build-21) Checking the system...
2024-04-08 11:53:52,597 INFO  [org.tes.DockerClientFactory] (build-21) ✔︎ Docker server version should be at least 1.6.0
2024-04-08 11:53:52,653 INFO  [tc.mongo:latest] (build-21) Creating container for image: mongo:latest
2024-04-08 11:53:53,395 INFO  [org.tes.uti.RegistryAuthLocator] (build-21) Credential helper/store (docker-credential-desktop) does not have credentials for https://index.docker.io/v1/
2024-04-08 11:53:53,455 INFO  [tc.tes.5.1] (build-21) Creating container for image: testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1
2024-04-08 11:53:53,653 INFO  [tc.tes.5.1] (build-21) Container testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1 is starting: 13b4229d8afb17d2f14e1e3c52e49150d0c9456dbe944c31bca63d5432938c7c
2024-04-08 11:53:55,003 INFO  [tc.tes.5.1] (build-21) Container testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1 started in PT1.5480268S
2024-04-08 11:53:55,176 INFO  [tc.mongo:latest] (build-21) Container mongo:latest is starting: 440cf84dde94121fed2904e95470eb85ae336fb28081da5614bcf6fb7c14f894
2024-04-08 11:53:57,429 INFO  [tc.mongo:latest] (build-21) Container mongo:latest started in PT4.7760203S

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start Quarkus test resource class de.dlh.lht.ams.jcc.util.RedisTestResourceLifecycleManager

    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.throwBootFailureException(QuarkusTestExtension.java:638)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.interceptTestClassConstructor(QuarkusTestExtension.java:722)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start Quarkus test resource class de.dlh.lht.ams.jcc.util.RedisTestResourceLifecycleManager
    at io.quarkus.test.common.TestResourceManager$TestResourceEntryRunnable.run(TestResourceManager.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to start Redis service
    at redis.embedded.RedisInstance.start(RedisInstance.java:44)
    at de.dlh.lht.ams.jcc.util.RedisTestResourceLifecycleManager.start(RedisTestResourceLifecycleManager.java:19)
    at io.quarkus.test.common.TestResourceManager$TestResourceEntryRunnable.run(TestResourceManager.java:500)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Ready pattern not found in log. Startup log: 
[32280] 08 Apr 11:54:00.302 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
[32280] 08 Apr 11:54:00.302 # Redis version=5.0.14.1, bits=64, commit=ec77f72d, modified=0, pid=32280, just started
[32280] 08 Apr 11:54:00.302 # Configuration loaded
[32280] 08 Apr 11:54:00.305 # Could not create server TCP listening socket 127.0.0.1:6379: bind: An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.
    at redis.embedded.RedisInstance.awaitServerReady(RedisInstance.java:51)
    at redis.embedded.RedisInstance.start(RedisInstance.java:40)
    ... 6 more

Here is Redis:
C:\Users\U765123>redis-server
[23696] 08 Apr 11:12:50.638 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
[23696] 08 Apr 11:12:50.638 # Redis version=5.0.14.1, bits=64, commit=ec77f72d, modified=0, pid=23696, just started
[23696] 08 Apr 11:12:50.639 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
                _._
           _.-``__ ''-._
      _.-``    `.  `_.  ''-._           Redis 5.0.14.1 (ec77f72d/0) 64 bit
  .-`` .-```.  ```\/    _.,_ ''-._
 (    '      ,       .-`  | `,    )     Running in standalone mode
 |`-._`-...-` __...-.``-._|'` _.-'|     Port: 6379
 |    `-._   `._    /     _.-'    |     PID: 23696
  `-._    `-._  `-./  _.-'    _.-'
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |           http://redis.io
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'
      `-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'
          `-._        _.-'
              `-.__.-'

[23696] 08 Apr 11:12:50.644 # Server initialized
[23696] 08 Apr 11:12:50.654 * DB loaded from disk: 0.009 seconds
[23696] 08 Apr 11:12:50.654 * Ready to accept connections

But:
C:\Users\U765123>PING 192.168.1.100

Pinging 192.168.1.100 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.100:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

and
C:\Users\U765123>redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379
127.0.0.1:6379>

I dont understand why this is happening. How can I troubleshoot and resolve the connectivity issue between my Quarkus application and Redis?Are there additional configuration settings or steps I should consider to ensure Redis is accessible during testing?
this is my lifecycle manager:
import io.quarkus.test.common.QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager;

import lombok.SneakyThrows;

import redis.embedded.RedisServer;

import java.util.Map;

public class RedisTestResourceLifecycleManager implements QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager {

    private RedisServer redisServer;

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> start() {
        redisServer = new RedisServer();
        redisServer.start();
        return null;
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public void stop() {
        redisServer.stop();
    }
}

I recentry get this:
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: ERR unknown command `getex`, with args beginning with: `cache:all-layover-panels:1242`, `EX`, `345600`, 

at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniBlockingAwait.await(UniBlockingAwait.java:79)
at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniAwait.atMost(UniAwait.java:65)
at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniAwait.indefinitely(UniAwait.java:46)
at io.quarkus.cache.runtime.CacheResultInterceptor.intercept(CacheResultInterceptor.java:153)
at io.quarkus.cache.runtime.CacheResultInterceptor_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:42)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:30)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:27)
at de.dlh.lht.ams.jcc.service.jobcard.PanelJobcardService_Subclass.getAllLayoverPanels(Unknown Source)
at de.dlh.lht.ams.jcc.service.jobcard.PanelJobcardService_ClientProxy.getAllLayoverPanels(Unknown Source)
at de.dlh.lht.ams.jcc.service.jobcard.PanelJobcardServiceTest.testGetAllLayoverPanels(PanelJobcardServiceTest.java:249)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.runExtensionMethod(QuarkusTestExtension.java:1013)
at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.interceptTestMethod(QuarkusTestExtension.java:827)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)

Caused by: ERR unknown command getex, with args beginning with: cache:all-layover-panels:1242, EX, 345600,

I think you're confusing 2 things. First, 192.168.1.100 clearly is not an IP address of your machine -- otherwise the ping 192.168.1.100 command wouldn't fail. Stop trying to use it. Second, the RedisTestResourceLifecycleManager that you wrote doesn't seem to work correctly. I don't know how it looks like, but the output contains a problematic piece: Could not create server TCP listening socket 127.0.0.1:6379: bind: An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket. This is what you need to resolve.

@Ladicek alright, I just updated my description. please check it out
